# Using miso.ds with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to use Miso Dataset ( http://misoproject.com/dataset/ )with requirejs and I'm wondering what's wrong with my require js definition (I'm pretty new to require AND miso), `Miso` will be `undefined` (the setup for jquery is ok)

```
require.config({
    // base url for vendor libs
    // files present : jquery.js, lodash.js, miso.ds.js, moment.js, underscore.deferred.js, underscore.math.js
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    // app components are stored in the js/app folder, so they'll start with 'app/'
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
    },

    shim: {
        // miso.ds shim, with its dependencies
        'miso.ds' : {
            deps : ['lodash', 'moment', 'underscore.deferred', 'underscore.math'],
            exports: 'Miso'
        }
    }
});

// start the main app logic.
require(['jquery', 'miso.ds'],
function ($, Miso) {
    console.log($);
    console.log(Miso);
});
```

Any idea?

Regards,

Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was also discussed here : https://github.com/misoproject/dataset/pull/174
It was a bug in Miso.
The 0.4.1 version fixed the issue.